# Limitar la longitud de un texto con JavScript(Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como puedo limitar una cadena de texto con javascript o jquery???

Tengo un dato traído desde la base de datos, pero ese dato es demasiado largo y me desmaqueta mi diseño, lo que quiero es por ejemplo, si ese dato es mayor a cierta cantidad de caracteres co javascript o jquery poner "..." sustituyendo al resto del parrafo, como puedo hacer eso??

Gracias de antemano :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.substring(0, 2);
var final = res +"...";
console.log(final);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me sirvió demasiado :)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto:

```
function recortar(){
   var logitud = 20;
   var dato = "texto largo";
   var datoAMostrar = "";

   for(var i = 0; i < logitud; i++)
       datoAMostrar = datoAMostrar + dato[i];

   datoAMostrar = datoAMostrar + "...";

}
```

Debes tener cuidado ya que si la longitud (numero de caracteres a mostrar) es mayor que el texto, te aparecerá un undefined. Esto se arreglaria de la siguiente forma:

```
function recortar(){
   var logitud = 20;
   var dato = "texto largo";
   var datoAMostrar = "";

   for(var i = 0; i < logitud && i < dato.length; i++)
       datoAMostrar = datoAMostrar + dato[i];

   datoAMostrar = datoAMostrar + "...";

}
```

Comment: Ya lo solucione con la primera respuesta amigo, pero gracias de antemano :)

Answer (score 1):

Es una solución parecida a las anteriores, pero a lo mejor es algo más corta que la segunda, y más elaborada que la primera:

```
function recortaDatos(dato,longitud){
    var respuesta = dato;
    if(dato.length>longitud){
       respuesta = dato.substring(0,longitud-3)+"...";
    }
    return respuesta;
}
```

Ahora, a la hora de recoger los datos, dentro del bucle que supongo que crearás para iterar entre esos datos, simplemente siempre pasa esos mismos datos por este filtro: (ejemplo)

```
for(var i =0; i<listado.length; i++){
      for (var j = 0; j< listado[i].length; j++){
           $(donde rellenes el dato).text(recortaDatos(listado[i][j]));
      }
}
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias, la verdad no lo probé pero me funciono la primera